# Split column names and create new column from data in column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have sensor data in a pandas dataframe that looks like:

```
Timestamp           1014.temperature    1014.humidity   1015.temperature    1015.humidity   1016.temperature    1016.humidity
2017-10-01 00:00:00 11.396667           92.440806       10.513333      92.204295            11.040000            92.959605
```

The `SensorID` is given by the 4-digit number before the dot in each column. `Timestamp` indexes the data. The data goes on for several more Timestamps and SensorIDs.

What can I do to retrieve the `SensorID` in each column to create a new column so that my dataframe looks like:

```
Timestamp            SensorID Temperature   Humidity
2017-10-01 00:00:00  1014     11.396667     92.440806
2017-10-01 00:00:00  1015     10.513333     92.204295
2017-10-01 00:00:00  1016     11.040000     92.959605
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) for `MultiIndex` in columns and reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with first level, last [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `rename`:

```
#if Timestamp is column
#df = df.set_index('Timestamp')

df.columns = df.columns.str.split('.', expand=True)
df = df.stack(level=0).reset_index().rename(columns={'level_1':'SensorID'})
print (df)
             Timestamp SensorID   humidity  temperature
0  2017-10-01 00:00:00     1014  92.440806    11.396667
1  2017-10-01 00:00:00     1015  92.204295    10.513333
2  2017-10-01 00:00:00     1016  92.959605    11.040000
```